# How to decide cluster size based on data size in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way we can decide spark cluster size based on data size instead of using whole cluster resources.

Tried assigning all resources and dynamic allocation

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use only data size metric to guide your decision on choosing the cluster size. At least two other resources are equally important:

1. Processing power (CPU) - depending on what you are calculating, the same dataset could have wildly different processing needs to accomplish what is intended in a reasonable amount of time.
2. Memory (RAM) - lack of RAM could mean spillovers to disk or even OOM exceptions (even worse, intermittent OOM exceptions!) and extreme slowdown of your processing jobs.

What I am trying to convey is that there is no recommended formula to calculate cluster size based on input data size, since it's only one dimension to look at when choosing a cluster size - there is no recommended CPU+RAM/MB of input data.

You should be choosing your cluster size depending on more than the discussed three points (input data size, CPU, RAM) like would it be a multitenant cluster? Would it be always on and waiting for data to be processed? If it is always running, what are its requirements for the storage of data, if any? Is it used more or less only as a processing engine, meaning more CPU is needed?

Choosing an optimal cluster size is not a straightforward question. Usually it boils down to trial and (expensive :) ) error. Good monitoring setup is crucial to act on any changes (in case of under provisioning to scale down resources, but have time to act to scale up when needed/have it automated to meet your changing needs).